# compare list of dictionaries to dataframe, show missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dictionaries

```
example_list = [{'email':'myemail@email.com'},{'email':'another@email.com'}]
```

and a dataframe with an 'Email' column

I need to compare the list against the dataframe and return the values that are not in the dataframe.

I can certainly iterate over the list, check in the dataframe, but I was looking for a more pythonic way, perhaps using list comprehension or perhaps a map function in dataframes?

Answer (score 1):

To return those values that are *not* in DataFrame.email, here's a couple of options involving set difference operations—

#### `np.setdiff1d`

```
emails = [d['email'] for d in example_list)]
diff = np.setdiff1d(emails, df['Email'])   # returns a list
```

---

#### `set.difference`

```
# returns a set
diff = set(d['email'] for d in example_list)).difference(df['Email'])
```

Comment: `set` methods can utilise hashing of elements. But clearly `df['Email']` is not pre-hashed. So my question is does hashing occur implicitly, or not at all?

Comment: @jpp ah, I get you... yeah, it's faster in most cases to build it like this, experience would show... try it out!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to take one `set` from another. For a functional solution you can use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res = set(map(itemgetter('email'), example_list)) - set(df['email'])
```

Note `-` is syntactic sugar for `set.difference`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up converting the list into a dataframe, comparing the two dataframes by merging them on a column, and then creating a dataframe out of the missing values

so, for example

```
    example_list = [{'email':'myemail@email.com'},{'email':'another@email.com'}]
    df_two = pd.DataFrame(item for item in example_list)
    common = df_one.merge(df_two, on=['Email'])
    df_diff = df_one[(~df_one.Email.isin(common.Email))]
```